# Widget binding with Gridster and Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, gridster

I am new to Javascript and trying to use Gridster with Knockout.  I have a database with items, and I use knockout foreach to bind them to a UL.  The UL is styled with the Gridster library.  Everything works great unless I try to add additional elements to the UL via the ObservableArray in the viewmodel.

Can anyone help me understand the scope and order of operations here?  It feels like the Gridster library isn't doing its styling to the new widgets.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5swe/) jsfiddle shows a working demo of the issue.  Notice when you double click on a widget, it creates a new one but doesn't place it in the grid.  Instead, it just kind of hangs out behind.

Here is the HTML

```
   <div class="gridster">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: myData">
            <li data-bind="attr:{

              'data-row':datarow,
              'data-col':datacol,
              'data-sizex':datasizex,
              'data-sizey':datasizey

        },text:text, doubleClick: $parent.AddOne"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is the Javascript

```
//This is some widget data to start the process
var gridData = [ {text:'Widget #1', datarow:1, datacol:1, datasizex:1, datasizey:1},
    {text:'Widget #2', datarow:2, datacol:1, datasizex:1, datasizey:1},
    {text:'Widget #3', datarow:1, datacol:2, datasizex:1, datasizey:1},
    {text:'Widget #4', datarow:2, datacol:2, datasizex:1, datasizey:1}];

// The viewmodel contains an observable array of widget data to be 
//    displayed on the gridster
var viewmodel = function () {

    var self = this;
    self.myData = ko.observableArray(gridData);
    //AddOne adds an element to the observable array 
    //   (called at runtime from doubleClick events)
    self.AddOne = function () {
        var self = this;
        myViewModel.myData.push({
            text: 'Widget Added After!',
            datarow: 1,
            datacol: 1,
            datasizex: 1,
            datasizey: 1
        });
    };

};


var myViewModel = new viewmodel();
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);

$(".gridster ul").gridster({
    widget_margins: [5, 5],
    widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140]
});
```

Comment: I updated the JSFiddle with some extra code that manually adds the widget to the gridster... thing.  It works as far as I can tell, but I am still not sure why and / or how.  

http://jsfiddle.net/Y5swe/3/

Comment: I made some progress on this again.  It looks like Gridster simply knows nothing about Knockout's adding elements.  The only advice I have now is to add them manually.  Here is the latest fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/Y5swe/13/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a full example in [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Be4cf/55/). Here, I have highlighted just the delete function

> ```
> self.deleteOne = function (item) {
>     console.log(item);
>     var widget = $("#" + item.id);
>     console.log(widget);
>     var column = widget.attr("data-col");
>     if (column) {
>         console.log('Removing ');
>         // if this is commented out then the widgets won't re-arrange
>         self.gridster.remove_widget(widget, function(){
>             self.myData.remove(item);
>             console.log('Tiles: '+self.myData().length);                
>         });
>     }
> };
> ```

The work of removing the element from the observable array is done inside the remove_widget callback. See gridster's [documentation](http://gridster.net/#remove_widget_method). Consequently, the removeGridster hook executed before a widget is removed, does no longer need to do the actual remove_widget call.

Comment: Great fiddle! It saved me from a lot of time figuring this out.  My only question is why doesn't it work if you initialize gridster within $() instead of using afterRender template?

Comment: Also, I found a limitation: no matter what you specify for the x and y size of the added widget in the addOne function, it is 1x1.

Comment: The 1x1 limitation can be mitigated by moving the `obj.datacol = parseInt(column);` and `obj.datarow = parseInt(widget.attr("data-row"));` rows before calling add_wiget in the `self.addGridster` function. Also add the following lines before the same add_widget call: `obj.datasizex` = parseInt(widget.attr("data-sizex"));` and `obj.datasizey` = parseInt(widget.attr("data-sizey"));`. You may also use `widget.data('col')` instead of `widget.attr('data-col')`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working solution that I think is more in line with the MVVM pattern:

http://jsfiddle.net/Be4cf/4/

```
//This is some widget data to start the process
var gridData = [
    {id: "1", text:'Widget #1', datarow:1, datacol:1, datasizex:1, datasizey:1},
    {id: "2", text:'Widget #2', datarow:1, datacol:2, datasizex:2, datasizey:1},
    {id: "3", text:'Widget #3', datarow:1, datacol:4, datasizex:1, datasizey:1},
    {id: "4", text:'Widget #4', datarow:2, datacol:1, datasizex:1, datasizey:2}];

// The viewmodel contains an observable array of widget data to be 
//    displayed on the gridster
var viewmodel = function () {

    var self = this;
    self.myData = ko.observableArray(gridData);
    self.nextId = 5;
    self.gridster = undefined;

    // AddOne adds an element to the observable array.
    // Notice how I'm not adding the element to gridster by hand here. This means  
    // that whatever the source of the add is (click, callback, web sockets event), 
    // the element will be added to gridster.
    self.addOne = function () {
    myViewModel.myData.push({
            text: 'Widget Added After!',
            datarow: 1,
            datacol: 1,
            datasizex: 1,
            datasizey: 1,
            id: self.nextId++
        });
    };

    // Called after the render of the initial list.
    // Gridster will add the existing widgets to its internal model.
    self.initializeGridster = function() {
        self.gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
            widget_margins: [5, 5],
            widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140]
        }).data('gridster');
    };

    // Called after the render of the new element.
    self.addGridster = function(data, object) {
        // This bypasses the add if gridster has not been initialized.
        if (self.gridster) {
            var $item = $(data[0].parentNode);

            // The first afterRender event is fired 2 times. It appears to be a bug in knockout.
            // I'm pretty new to knockout myself, so it might be a feature too! :)
            // This skips the second call from the initial fired event.
            if (!$item.hasClass("gs-w"))
            {
                // This removes the binding from the new node, since gridster will re-add the element.
                ko.cleanNode(data[0].parentNode);
                // Adds the widget to gridster.
                self.gridster.add_widget($item);
                // We must update the model with the position determined by gridster
                object.datarow = parseInt($item.attr("data-row"));
                object.datacol = parseInt($item.attr("data-col"));
            }
        }
    };
};

var myViewModel = new viewmodel();
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
```

I still need to think about the remove and move events (a move in gridster should update the item's x and y values in the viewmodel). I started using knockout yesterday, so any help would be appreciated.

I couldn't find a cdn for the latest version of gridster. JSFiddle points to a temporary website I've added in Azure, I'll leave it up for a few days, but feel free to update it with your own link.

/------------------------------ UPDATE ----------------------------------/

I've updated my code to support deletions and moving widgets (http://jsfiddle.net/Be4cf/11/) but there's a small caveat: there's an open issue (https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1130) that knockout cleans out jquery data before calling the beforeRemove event. This causes gridster to crash since the data needed to move the other items around is kept in a data element. A workaround could be to keep a copy of the data and to re-add it to the element later, but I've chosen the lazy way and commented the offending line in knockout.

Comment: Your solution isn't not complete. What happens if you want to add a Widget into a specific row and column?

I think you are failing to realise that Gridster does not watch the DOM element for changes. Once you understand this, you will then understand why the call to `add_widget` is necessary — you are initially updating the DOM element without informing Gridster about it.

If I were you I would just get rid of the KnockoutJS view (.html), and go down the route of just doing everything through the Gridster API methods.

Answer (score 0):

Add class="gs_w"  to ur li in gridster it should work

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that doesn't work.  You can try that advice out yourself on this jsfiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/Y5swe/13/

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like below. `addNewGridElement` is called - with the rendered DOM element which is important in Gridster's case as `gridster.add_widget` accepts a DOM element as its first argument - once you've added something to the Knockout observable. After this, it's just a matter of then adding `domNode` to Gridster.

**view.html:**

```
   <div class="gridster">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: { myData, afterAdd: $root.addNewGridElement }">
            <li data-bind="attr:{

              'data-row':datarow,
              'data-col':datacol,
              'data-sizex':datasizex,
              'data-sizey':datasizey

        },text:text, doubleClick: $parent.AddOne"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**view.js:**

```
self.addNewGridElement = function (domNode, index, newTile) {
    // Filter non li items - this will remove comments etc. dom  nodes.
    var liItem = $(domNode).filter('li');
    if ( liItem.length > 0 ) {
        // Add new Widget to Gridster
        self.gridster.add_widget(domNode, newTile.x, newTile.y, newTile.row, newTile.col);
    }
};
```