# Widget HTML Content Binding with Gridster and Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, gridster

This is related to another topic posted on [Widget binding with Gridster and Knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549122/widget-binding-with-gridster-and-knockout/20080711#20080711)

The widget binding is fine however I am trying to bind values within each widget. So consider the following data setup as an observable array

```
{id: "1", text:'Title', datarow:1, datacol:1, datasizex:1, datasizey:1}
```

I have the following HTML bindings within each widget

```
<input data-bind="value: text"/>

<span class="text" data-bind="text: text"></span>
```

The UI is not updating when a new value is entered. See http://jsfiddle.net/Be4cf/31/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the text property into an observable :

```
{id: "1", text:ko.observable('Widget #1'), datarow:1, datacol:1, datasizex:1, datasizey:1},
{id: "2", text:ko.observable('Widget #2'), datarow:1, datacol:2, datasizex:2, datasizey:1},
{id: "3", text:ko.observable('Widget #3'), datarow:1, datacol:4, datasizex:1, datasizey:1},
{id: "4", text:ko.observable('Widget #4'), datarow:2, datacol:1, datasizex:1, datasizey:2}
```

You can also add `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` to the input, so the observable will be set on the key down event.

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Be4cf/32/)